# How to populate one drop-down based on the selection of another drop-down from database in php and javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to populate the drop-down based on the selection of other. Here's how the database looks like. Tried the following code but it isn't giving me any results.

```
make
id maker
2   Apple
3   Samsung


model
id make_id model
1    3      Galaxy S III
2    3      Galaxy S IV
3    2        iphone 5s
4    2        iphone 5
```

Queries.php

```
class Queries{
    public static function getMaker() {
       $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * from make"  ;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
         $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    }
    public static function getModel($make_id) {
    $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * from model WHERE make_id = :make_id"  ;     
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':make_id', $make_id);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
         $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    }
}
```

mobilereg.php

```
$make_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "make_id");
 require_once './pages/header.php';
  require_once './functions/queries.php';
  $maker = Queries::getMaker();
   $model = Queries::getModel($make_id);

 <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Make</label>
<select class="form-control"name="maker"id="maker"onchange="get_models();">
        <option selected disabled></option>
        <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($maker); $i++) {
            echo '<option value="' . $maker[$i]['id'] . '">' . $maker[$i]['maker'] .  '</option>';
        }
        ?>
            </select>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Model</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="get_models" id="get_models">
        <option selected disabled></option>

            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

main.js

```
function get_models(){
    var maker = $('#maker').val();
    var dataString = "maker="+maker;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "functions.php", 
    data: dataString,
    success: function(html)
    {
        $("#get_models").html(html);
    }
});
}
```

functions.php

```
require_once './queries.php';

$make_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "make_id");

if($_POST){
    $maker = $_POST['maker'];
    if($maker!=''){
    echo Queries::getModel($make_id);
    echo "<select name='get_models'>";

   echo "<option value='" . $row['make_id'] . "'>" . $row['model'] . " 
 </option>";
       echo '</select>';
    }
}
```

So maker and model are the two drop-downs. The options in the model should result on the basis of the selection we make in the maker drop-down.

I've referred the code from one the questions here but it doesn't work at all. The problem is in the functions.php I guess. I'm very new to php and js, any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: "it doesn't work at all" isn't a helpful problem statement.  What _is_ happening?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: Okay so when I select an option in the maker, there's nothing in the model drop-down.

Comment: Does the `get_models()` run?  If so, does the ajax request get fired?  If so, is the data sent what you expect?  If so, what is the response?  Is it what you expect?  These are all debugging steps that you need to do on your own to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: And how do i check that? There's no error in the console

Comment: Start by putting a `console.log('something');` at the top of your `get_models()` function.  If you see the output in your console, then it's getting called.  If you don't, then it's not.  For the rest, look in your Network tab of the debugger.  Research on debugging Javascript and ajax code.